# http to https stuck in infinite loop

Tags: https

I followed every step, cleared all mixed content warnings/errors but as soon as I change the `home_url` and `site_url` to https it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

if I only change the `site_url` it's the admin panel who get stuck in a redirect loop.

I also noticed the following redirect loops:

1. https://example.com/blog -> https://www.example.com/blog
2. https://www.example.com/blog -> http://www.example.com/blog/
3. http://www.example.com/blog/ -> https://www.example.com/blog/

I can't seem to find why where it forces the trailing slash (number 2) but I think it's Wordpress doing this.

Did I forget to do something specific?

WP version: **4.7.6**

Plugins:

- BackUpWordPress
- Bunyad Page Builder
- Bunyad Shortcodes
- Bunyad Widgets
- Dynamic Featured Image
- Facebook Open Graph, Google+ and Twitter Card Tags
- HTTP / HTTPS Remover
- Lazy Facebook Comments
- Meta Box
- Quick Featured Images
- Redirection
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- Simple Follow Me Social Buttons Widget
- Relevanssi
- Slim Jetpack
- Speciale Sidebars
- WordPress Importeerder
- WP All Export
- WP Missed Schedule
- WP Retina 2x
- WP Smush
- WP Super Cache
- WP-PostViews
- WPML Compatibility Test Tools
- WPML Multilingual CMS
- XML Sitemap & Google Nieuws feeds
- and a custom plugin

Comment: Does your permalink-setting use a trailing slash? What's your server environment like? Does WP recognize that a connection is secure ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")? Is it really a loop (3 going back to start at 1?) or is it just 3 redirects that you want to shorten to one?

Answer (score 0):

backup the htaccess file and delete it..

clear the browser cache..

go to your database yourprefix_options table

change the siteurl and home with https://example.com/blog

i am assuming you are running wordpress on the subdirectory called blog if not the case change the url to https://example.com and open the wp admin with https link

go to settings permalink and click on save changes..

and as you have WP Smush & WP Super Cache installed do clear all the cache first to avoid any issues.

I hope it'll solve your issue